# Async functions returning undefined/pending promises, but await not allowed in code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have looked through similar issues without finding a solution I am able to implement into my own code, therefore I make this post. I have the following code:

```
async function getProgram(id) {
    let study = "";
    pool.query('SELECT name FROM Programs WHERE id=?', [id], (error, result) => {
      if (error) return console.error(error); // If error, show error in console (in red text) and return
      console.log(result[0].name);
      return result[0].name;
    });
    
    return study;
}

let program = (id) => {
  await getProgram(id)
    .then(study => {
        return study;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

console.log(program(2));
```

The last console.log returns undefined, although the console log in the pool.query gives the correct string I am looking for. Another version of this code that I tried gave Promise pending instead of undefined.

From reading other posts I understand this to be because I am not using await somewhere together with the async function. The problem is that if I try to insert await in the last console.log: `console.log(await program(2));`
or in the program function: `let program = (id) => { await getProgram(id) ...` I get an error telling me `Unexpected reserved word 'await'`.

I am still very new to promises/async/await so I am sure I am missing something elementary.. Thanks for all help.

Comment: Suggestions: First explain in general what are you trying to do? I suggest you to read a bit more about promises, especially the difference between async/await approach and then/catch approach, looks like you are mixing them up. about your code the function program does not return  `await getProgram(id)` it must return the promise. second you are console logging the promise and not the result of the promise, you need to do then in order to log it `program(2).then(res => console.log(res))` ( I suggested you then because you cannot use await outside async function. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can only use await inside of async functions. You should define program like this:

```
let program = async (id) => {
  await getProgram(id)
    .then(study => {
        return study;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Following that, now program is a promise and `console.log(program(2))` wouldn't print the resolved promise. To do that you'ld need to use some other syntax like:

```
program(2).then(result => console.log(result));
```

It has to be done this way as `await` can't be used on top-level code (at least not in all browsers /node engines).

Finally, I think you should also rewrite getProgram as follows:

```
function getProgram(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        pool.query('SELECT name FROM Programs WHERE id=?', [id], (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error); // If error, show error in console (in red text) and return
                reject(error)
            }
            console.log(result[0].name);
            resolve(result[0].name);
       });
    });
}
```

Notice how `study` wasn't doing anything and how you need to transform the pool async function into a promise

Comment: Thank you, but I am still encountering some problem. ```console.log(program(2))``` as you said returns a promise that is fullfilled, but the last line you included unfortunetly results in undefined still. This is the promise I get if I do ```console.log(program(2))```:
```Promise
__proto__: Promise
catch: ƒ catch()
constructor: ƒ Promise()
finally: ƒ finally()
then: ƒ then()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"

__proto__: Object

[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined```

I am thinking that the problem now lies in my query (the getProgram(id) function)

Comment: Yes, I hadn't notice but you had some issues on getProgram as well. Updated the answer with my solution